# Repeated style attribute in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an AngularJS directive which specifies `replace: true` and `template: <span style="color: red;"></span>`. Whenever I use the directive in my markup, it seems that the contents of the `style` attribute is repeated in the DOM: `<span style="color: red;;color: red;"></span>`. Is this a bug in AngularJS, or am I doing something wrong here?

Here is a Plunk that demonstrates the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/UMhmjGS3XW84d7zctujo

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you use inline-styles instead of stylesheets?

Comment: I'm just using inline styles for now, I stumbled upon this odd behaviour and got curious as to why it's happening.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what causes this, but it won't harm to list a possible solution.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {$scope.style={color:red};);

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    template: '<span ng-style="style" class="my-test-class">something!</span>'
  };
 });
```

See: [**ngStyle**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angStyle)

Comment: Thanks! I think what causes this is this line (and the following?): https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L1634